# Laravel routing behavior with PJAX not as expected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, pjax

I'm building my first lavavel website from scratch and I've run into a behavioral issue with a few routes.

Here is the relevant code for my routes file:

```
Route::get('work', 'PageController@work');
Route::get('work/{item}', 'PageController@workitem');
```

And here are the relevant methods:

```
public function work() {
        return view('pages.work');
    }

    public function workitem($item) {
        $v = 'work.'.$item;
        if(view()->exists($v)) {
            return view($v);
        } else {
            return view('errors.noitem');
        }
    }
```

And here is the relevant part of my view:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
...
<div class="workflex">
    <a class="workitem" href="/work/test"></a>
    <a class="workitem" href="/work/test2"></a>
</div>
<div id="loadContent" class="loadContent">
    @yield('insert')
</div>
...
@stop
```

It is worth mentioning that I intend to load the individual workitem pages with PJAX. I have views that the PJAX loads into the the "insert" section based on the URL:

```
$(document).pjax('a.workitem', '#loadContent');
```

The user loads the initial work page at the /work subdirectory, and clicks a button to load /work/item pages with PJAX. As the routes suggest, I also want the user to be able to enter a workitem into the URL and be directed to the work page already loaded with that item. This whole system behaves as intended... until I added the following jquery to work.blade.php:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
        $('#loadContent').load("/work/init", function() {
            myFade('#loadContent > *', 1); //ignore this function, it's an animation irrelevant to my problem
        });
    });
```

This is here as an attempt to load a initial message inside the PJAX loading div #loadContent to tell the user to select a workitem. However, a side effect of this is that now whenever I browser to a /work/item directly (PJAX still loads the pages correctly) the document triggers this jquery and the message overrides the page content.

I was brainstorming ways to allow the work() method in my controller to trigger something that loads this script or passes just the work/init view into the "insert" section.

What do you think would be the best way to solve this? Your answers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question. I forgot about the route optional parameters. I changed/added these things:

```
Route::get('work/{item?}', 'PageController@work');
```

and in my controller:

```
public function work($item = 'init') {
        $v = 'work.'.$item;
        if(view()->exists($v)) {
            return view($v);
        } else {
            return view('errors.noitem');
        }
    }
```

Works perfectly now!